# How can I configure sonar-maven-plugin to accept Java 9 module-info.java files?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, java-module, sonar-maven-plugin

How can I configure sonar-maven-plugin in my parent pom to accept (or ignore) Java 9 `module-info.java` files?

After adding `module-info.java` files to my Maven multi module project our `mvn sonar:sonar` executions started failing. After reading about [BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_filefilters.html), I tried to add a configuration file to the project root folder:

*folder structure*

```sh
parent
  |
  + pom.xml
  + checkstyle.xml
  |
  + submodule
  |   + pom.xml
  |   + more files
  |
  + more submodules
```

*checkstyle.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
        "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
        "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <!-- BeforeExecutionFileFilters is required for sources that are based on java9 -->
    <module name="BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter">
        <property name="fileNamePattern" value="module\-info\.java$"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

*pom.xml*

```xml
    <properties>
        <!-- 
            attempt to point to the checkstyle config location 
            which seems to be wrong as Sonar generates a new config 
            file in the Maven submodule /target/sonar directory
        -->
        <checkstyle.config.location>checkstyle.xml</checkstyle.config.location>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.9.1.2184</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

However, it seems like `sonar-maven-plugin` is not picking up the checkstyle configuration file:

*output*

```sh
mvn sonar:sonar


[INFO] SonarQube version: 8.9.6
[INFO] Default locale: "en_GB", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[INFO] Load global settings
[INFO] Load global settings (done) | time=881ms
[INFO] User cache: ~/.sonar/cache
[INFO] Load/download plugins
[INFO] Load plugins index
[INFO] Load plugins index (done) | time=171ms
[INFO] Load/download plugins (done) | time=409ms
[INFO] Loaded core extensions: developer-scanner
[INFO] JavaScript/TypeScript frontend is enabled
[INFO] Process project properties
[INFO] Process project properties (done) | time=13ms
[INFO] Execute project builders
[INFO] Execute project builders (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] Project key: [my parent project name]
[INFO] Base dir: ~/projects/[my parent project name]
[INFO] Working dir: ~/projects/[my parent project name]/target/sonar
[INFO] Load project settings for component key: '[my parent project name]'
[INFO] Load branch configuration
[INFO] Found manual configuration of branch/PR analysis. Skipping automatic configuration.
[INFO] Load branch configuration (done) | time=3ms
[INFO] Load quality profiles
[INFO] Load quality profiles (done) | time=295ms
[INFO] Load active rules
[INFO] Load active rules (done) | time=5305ms
[INFO] Indexing files...

[INFO] Project configuration:
[INFO] Indexing files 
[INFO] 0 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
[INFO] Quality profile for java: Sonar way
[INFO] Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
[INFO] ------------- Run sensors on module [my submodule name]
[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java]
[INFO] Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 11
[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization
[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization (done) | time=7ms
[INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization
[INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization (done) | time=2ms
[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan
[INFO] 2 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] Load project repositories
[INFO] Load project repositories (done) | time=113ms
[INFO] 2/2 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan (done) | time=1334ms
[INFO] Java Test Files AST scan
[INFO] 2 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] 2/2 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Java Test Files AST scan (done) | time=150ms
[INFO] Java Generated Files AST scan
[INFO] 0 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] 0/0 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Java Generated Files AST scan (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java] (done) | time=1799ms
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java]
[INFO] parsing [~/projects/[project name]/target/surefire-reports]
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java] (done) | time=77ms
[INFO] Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
[INFO] 1 source file to be analyzed
[INFO] 1/1 source file has been analyzed
[INFO] Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=138ms
[INFO] Sensor HTML [web]
[INFO] Sensor HTML [web] (done) | time=3ms
[INFO] Sensor XML Sensor [xml]
[INFO] 1 source file to be analyzed
[INFO] 1/1 source file has been analyzed
[INFO] Sensor XML Sensor [xml] (done) | time=115ms
[INFO] Sensor CheckstyleSensor [checkstyle]
[INFO] Checkstyle output report: ~/projects/[my subproject name]/target/sonar/checkstyle-result.xml
[INFO] Checkstyle configuration: ~/projects/[my subproject name]/target/sonar/checkstyle.xml
[INFO] Checkstyle charset: UTF-8
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project [my parent project name]: Can not execute Checkstyle: Exception was thrown while processing ~/[my subproject name]/src/main/java/module-info.java: NoViableAltException occurred while parsing file ~/[my project name]/src/main/java/module-info.java. unexpected token: module -> [Help 1]
```

Comments:

- Sonar generates a `target/sonar/checkstyle.xml` file which is different from the one I have attempted to add:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC 
        "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN" 
        "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<!-- Generated by Sonar -->
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="SuppressWarningsFilter" />
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="SuppressWarningsHolder"/> 
        <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter" />
    </module>
</module>
```

- I am unable to change the [Quality Profiles](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/quality-profiles/) on the SonarQube server as I am lacking privileges